# How do I create CharacterSet from other CharacterSet?

Tags: swift

```
let firstSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-()")
let secondSet = CharacterSet.whitespaces
```

I need to replace `+48 (23) 899899 098` with `+4823899899098`.

```
let output = "+48 (23) 899899 098".components(separatedBy: firstSet).joined(separator: "")
```

but here I need to use two CharacterSets. How can I join them into one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`union(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/characterset/1780295-union) for that.

```
let output = "+48 (23) 899899 098".components(separatedBy: firstSet.union(secondSet)).joined()
```

Comment: Curiously, the `union(_:)` call seems broken at the IBM Swift Sandbox: `a.union(b)` results in `a`, even if `b` is not a subset of `a`. Could someone else reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: @dfri It's strange I have just tried with IBM Swift Sandbox and also with https://iswift.org/playground but both are results in `a` for `a.union(b)`, the same thing is working with Xcode 8.

Comment: I found [this open bug report (SR-2509)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2509) covering the same issue for the `formUnion(_:)` method of `CharacterSet` (Swift 2.2), and added a comment prompting that this is still an issue in Swift 3 @ Linux, and also for the `union(_:)` method of `CharacterSet`.

Comment: You can use `.joined()` for empty string separator

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the suggestion, Edited answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use *regular expression*:

```
let output = "+48 (23) 899899 098"
let trimmedOutput = output.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9+]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
// -> +4823899899098"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function for phone formatting, so it would be reusable through app

```
//removes "(", ")", "-", " " etc. and adds "+" for region code format 
extension String {
    func phoneToString() -> String {
        var value = "+"
        for character in self.characters {
            if Int(String(character)) != nil {
                value = value + String(character)
            }
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

`let phoneWithoutSpaces = "+48 (23) 899899 098".phoneToString()`